# Run a command on startup of a server

Tags: linux

I want to have a command run when I boot/reboot a server.

I found [the same solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598195/how-to-add-a-script-to-startup-applications-from-the-command-line) everywhere, which is to make a `.desktop` file in `~/.config/startup/`.

But it did not work.

I tried copying the .desktop file on my computer, and it works fine. It's just on the server that it doesn't work

Comment: Which Linux versions on your computer and on the server? Do you want a boot script or a logon script (`~` needs logon)?

Comment: What Linux are you using, but you have to put it in the /etc/rc files, as well what are you trying to start up?

Comment: @harrymc I am running Linux mint 19.2 for both. I do not know the difference between boot script and logon script, which one is better? The command I want to run is for performing a port forwarding.

Comment: Port forwarding is usually done in the router and not in Linux. Please explain why you wish to do it this way.

Comment: @harrymc It's okay, I found a workaround for the port forwarding. But I am also running minecraft one the server, and I would like to run a command that starts the game whenever the server reboots. Do you know what's the best way to do this?

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-minecraft-server-setup